# radius or wpa2 error? - comptia network+

Tags: radius, wpa2

Im taking the COMPTIA Network+ exam on thursday and have this practice question I dont understand the difference:

Users connecting to an SSID appear to be unable to authenticate to the captive portal. Which of the following is the cause of this issue?
A. WPA2 security key
B. SSL certificates
C. CSMA/CA
D. RADIUS
Correct Answer: D

My question is how do you know it is a RADIUS problem and not a bad wpa2 password

Comment: The answer they list as correct does not make sense for the question. None of them do, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad wpa2 password wouldn't let you connect to hotspot which is a prerequisite to see the captive portal. Additionally captive portal usually means the wifi network is open - meaning no wep/wpa/wpa2 at all.

Comment: thank you, isnt the captive portal just the sign on prompt?

Comment: Yes, it is. But it is served from web server and to get there you must have some kind of networking connection already established. After signing in you are just getting unrestricted (or likely more correct - less restricted) access.